# Scala: Can we combine guard conditions with pattern matches up front within the sealed case class declarations

Tags: scala

Is it possible to combine guard conditions with pattern matching within sealed case class declarations?

I realise its possible to include guard conditions within the match block but I feel it would be beneficial to define this conditions up front in the sealed case classes.
This would allow developers to define strict set of possible inputs which the compiler would  check when pattern matching.

So in summary I'd like to be able to do the equivalent of something like this:

```
// create a set of pattern matchable cases with guards built in

sealed abstract class Args
case class ValidArgs1(arg1:Int,arg2:Int) if arg1>1 && arg2<10 extends Args
case class ValidArgs2(arg1:Int,arg2:Int) if arg1>5 && arg2<6 extends Args
case class InvalidArgs(arg1:Int,arg2:Int) if arg1<=1 && arg2>=10 extends Args


// the aim of this is to achieve pattern matching against an exhaustive set of 
// pre-defined possibilities

def process(args:Args){
    args match 
    {
        case ValidArgs1 = > // do this
        case ValidArgs2= > // do this
        case InvalidArgs = > // do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

+1 for an interesting speculative question. Since you are not operating at the type level, you cannot verify the instantiation at compile time, except maybe for very special checks with macros, e.g. when you are passing literals to the constructor.

On the other hand, your scenario, the pattern matching, is a runtime action. For that to work, you could use extractors instead of case classes.

```
case class Args(arg1: Int, arg2: Int)
object ValidArgs1 {
  def apply(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): Args = {
    val res = Args(arg1, arg2)
    require(unapply(res))
    res
  }
  def unapply(args: Args): Boolean = args.arg1 > 1 && args.arg2 < 10
}

def process(args: Args) = args match {
  case ValidArgs1() => "ok"
  case _            => "invalid"
}

process(ValidArgs1(2, 9))
process(Args(1, 10))
process(Args(3, 4))
```

Comment: Actually I think its nearly there, maybe we could build add the apply and unapply methods into the case class, then seal it to give us compile time checks to ensure we map a pathway of execution for the type, but only match and execute the pathway if the apply/ unapply condition is meet?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you will be able to have general constraints/assertions that are checked at compile-time in Scala, because Scala does not have a [static verifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) which would be needed to do this. If you are interested, have a look at (research) languages/tools such as [ESC/Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/Java), [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/), [Dafny](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/dafny/) or [VeriFast](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.jacobs/verifast/).

There might be ways of having a very limited amount of static checking with the regular compiler Scala by using [type-level programming](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) or [Scala macros](http://scalamacros.org/), but this is just a wild guess of mine, as I am not familiar with either of them. To be honest, I must admit that I would be quite surprised if macros can actually help here.

What works is runtime assertion checking, e.g.

```
case class Foo(arg1: Int, arg2: Int) {
  require(arg1 < arg2, "The first argument must be strictly less than " +
                       "the second argument.")
}

Foo(0, 0)
  /* java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
   *     The first argument must be strictly less than the second
   *     argument.
   */
```

but that isn't probably what you had in mind.

Comment: The suggested functionality requires no more the scala already has. It is just a syntax sugar.

Comment: @ayvango Scala definitely has no support for static verification. What do you mean, and why the downvote?

Comment: topic starter need no static verification. He just wants unapply method extended with provided hints.

Comment: @ayvango The OP wrote "This would allow developers to define strict set of possible inputs which the compiler would check when pattern matching.". Runtime checking is NOT done by the compiler, static verification is (well, by a verifier, but as a phase during the compilation).

Comment: all the pattern matching is not done by compiler in static. Compiler generates code to pattern match while running. It doesn't matter whether the guards are present or not.

Comment: @ayvango I have the strong feeling that we are talking at cross purposes here.